# Xlsxwriter module works in Atom, but not IDLE for more complex programs

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I've installed xlsxwriter via terminal, with every method outlined in the docs, sudo, easy install etc, uninstalling between.

I have run the demo script successfuly with CMD + I in atom, with the demo xlsx file being placed with the text in the cell - no problems there.

As soon as I run this in IDLE however, I get the traceback:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'

The module is in the frameworks directory - I'm just baffled as to why IDLE wouldn't be recognising the module when atom does?

I've searched high and low for similar issues but cannot seem to locate a workaround - this is the first itme i've run into this kind of problem with python modules.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

the module is listed in my pip and pip3 list:

pip3 list
Package            Version

---

imageio            2.6.1
numpy              1.17.4 
Pillow             7.0.0
pip                19.0.3 
progress           1.5
python-xmp-toolkit 2.0.1
pytz               2019.3 
rawkit             0.6.0
rawpy              0.13.1 
setuptools         40.8.0 
tqdm               4.38.0 
Wand               0.5.8
XlsxWriter         1.2.8
xlwt               1.3.0

Is there any reason why the IDLE shell would not recognise an installed module?

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments of any sort?

Comment: @AMC no, just running IDLE on a mac, which is the shell i use to run a file handling program I've put together, I'm just at a point where I want to take a look at writing some results to a file and am getting the error